# cnoremap <CR> <CR> breaks search fold opening

Tags: key-bindings, search, folding, jumplist

In order to switch between relative and absolute line numbering upon entering command-line, I `noremap <expr> <CR>` to `"someStuff"`.

Unfortunately this breaks the `foldopen`-ing feature for forward searches.

It already happens with the following line

```
cnoremap <CR> <CR>
```

### MWE

entire `.vimrc`

```
set foldmethod=marker
"default foldopen
set foldopen=block,hor,mark,percent,quickfix,search,tag,undo
cnoremap <CR> <CR>
```

text file

```
{{{
lkj
}}}
```

maneuver : normal-mode-type `/lkj<CR>`

and the fold does not open

comment the `cnoremap` reload and do the same, the fold does open

### Attempts

I somewhat managed to walk around the issue with a silly hack such as :

```
cnoremap <CR> <CR>i<C-c>
```

unfortunately this breaks the `repeat (.)` history.

The following works :

```
cnoremap <CR> <CR>mf.u`f
```

except at the opening of a vim session, when the `.` repeat does nothing.

Is there some way to achieve the `cnoremap`ping `<CR> <CR>` in a fully transparent way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [`:h 'foldopen'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27foldopen%27) states:

> NOTE: When the command is part of a mapping this option is not used.
>     Add the |zv| command to the mapping to get the same effect.
>     (rationale: the mapping may want to control opening folds itself)

So you should add the `zv` to your mapping, e.g. `cnoremap <cr> <cr>zv`